# Is it possible to configure iOS native HTML5 date picker?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, iphone, html

I'm using the native date and time pickers with type=date for the mobile version of a website. I want to able to configure the iOS native HTML5 datetime picker keyboard to be RTL for arabic. Is that's possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

This is not something you can configure on the HTML side.  When using type=date, it's up to the browser to determine what UI to pull up for date picking.

iOS would have to have a custom date/time picker for Arabic and a user's iOS language would need to be set to Arabic for this to work.  (I'm not sure if a custom Arabic date/time picker is something iOS supports.)

Comment: Thanks! I were swtiching to arabic, but the date format is not RTL. Wonder if that's a bug. Is there any documentation I can find on the iOS html5 datepicker?

Answer (score 1):

Native implementation is just like the keyboard - you can't touch or alter it in any way.

I set my phone to Arabic and touched an input with type="date" and this is what I get. Not sure if it's what you expect or not, as i don't speak Arabic. I also set the language on the html element to ar.

[image: arabic html5 picker]